Geo Node Sample Average Material
With Geo Nodes I am generating spheres along a mesh with multiple materials, I would like to have the spheres inherit the materials they are closest to and when along a border to average the shaders based on distance, in example if the left is red and the right side of the mesh is blue the speres in the middle should be purple.

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
